# Cannot configure PostgresSQL extension for php in Cpanel

Tags: apache-http-server, php, postgresql, cpanel, centos-6.6

I have a Centos 6.6 x86_64 vps cloud server with WHM and cpanel. It contains easyapache installed in it and working fine. php sites are working fine with it.
I have installed PostgresSQL 9.3 in the server via ssh.

Now when I transfered project to the server, I am not able to connect to the my postgres database as it says php extension `php_pgsql` is not installed in the server.

I checked through WHM (easyapache update option) to find that `php_pgsql` is installed and selected. But when I give:
`php -m` in command-line through ssh it doesn't show `php_pgsql` means  the service is not installed.

Since Cpanel is installed I am not able to install the extension via yum using `yum install php-pgsql*` saying the package is not found.

To my assumption the problem is that I didn't use the `/script/installpostgres` script provided by cpanel to install postgres server. I didn't want to install that because I need the version 9.3 of postgres which is not provided by the cpanel as it support only the version given by the linux distro for that release.

Also from https://features.cpanel.net/topic/support-postgres-93-and-above_2 I got to know that cpanel is not going to support postgres-9.3

**Is there a way by which I can connect Postgres 9.3 that i manually installed to php or Is there any way by which I can install postgres 9.3 with php support through cpanel.**

**Thanks,
Vivek**

Comment: The package is named php-pgsql, not php_pgsql. And why you can't install it via yum? Have you try to download and install it via rpm?

Comment: yes, i tried via rpm install and shows a lot of dependency problem

Comment: Have you tried with yum?

Comment: yes, it says package not found. but i was able to install it in my local server where cpanel is not there.

Comment: my project is working fine in my local server.

Comment: So download dependencies and install them with one rpm command

Comment: Can you tell me where should i point my extensions in php.ini. Read that it should point to a php-pgsql.so. i searched my server but didnt find it

Comment: extention=.... http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php

Comment: Is it possible to  assign the path of postgres to pg-sql through php.ini or something like that. php extension is not identifying the postgres installation or its path